# How can I get the sum of values in a pandas column that meet certain conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my csv I am working with:

```
oci,citing,cited,creation,timespan,journal_sc,author_sc
0200100000236252421370109080537010700020300040001-020010000073609070863016304060103630305070563074902,"10.1002/pol.1985.170230401","10.1007/978-1-4613-3575-7_2",1985-04,P2Y,no,no
...
```

The function to process data frame

```
def do_process_citation_data(f_path):
    global my_ocan

    my_ocan = pd.read_csv("citations.csv",
                          names=['oci', 'citing', 'cited', 'creation', 'timespan', 'journal_sc', 'author_sc'],
                          parse_dates=['creation', 'timespan'])
    my_ocan = my_ocan.iloc[1:]  # to remove the first row iloc - to select data by row numbers
    my_ocan['creation'] = pd.to_datetime(my_ocan['creation'], format="%Y-%m-%d", yearfirst=True)
    my_ocan['timespan'] = my_ocan['timespan'].apply(parse)
    # Period parsing on my_ocan['timespan']
    #print(my_ocan['timespan'])
    print(my_ocan.head())

    return my_ocan
#print(my_ocan.head())
                                                 oci  ... author_sc
1  020010107073600090601000000060105060106040500-...  ...        no
2  02007050504361421181514370302080202-0200101000...  ...        no
3  0200101040536030109070002063703010907000500-02...  ...        no
4  020010009033611181136111133000507-020010100083...  ...        no
5  0200100000736090708630363030109630608020004630...  ...        no

[5 rows x 7 columns]

#print(my_ocam.info())

RangeIndex: 213 entries, 1 to 213
Data columns (total 7 columns):
oci           213 non-null object
citing        213 non-null object
cited         213 non-null object
creation      213 non-null datetime64[ns]
timespan      213 non-null int64
journal_sc    213 non-null object
author_sc     213 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(5)

print(my_ocan['creation'].head())
print(my_ocan['timespan'].head())

1   2016-07-10
2   2018-03-01
3   2018-01-01
4   2017-06-13
5   2017-01-01
Name: creation, dtype: datetime64[ns]
1     486
2    1080
3     730
4     824
5     365
Name: timespan, dtype: int64
```

I am writing a function that returns a tuples of two items containing the number of the docs created in a particular year accompanied by the average time of 'timespan' of the docs created in that year.

```
def do_get_citations_per_year(data, year):
    result = tuple()
    y = ocinumber(year)
    n = time(year)
    result = (y, n)
```

I managed to get the total number of documents by using the .loc:

```
def ocinumber(year):
    result = tuple()
    my_ocan['creation'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_ocan['creation']).year
    lenta = len(my_ocan.loc[my_ocan['creation'] == year, 'creation'])
    return lenta
    #i.e running with 2015 return 99
```

Unfortunately, when I am using the same .loc method with a different condition it does not return me any result. The idea is to take the sum of all the values in ['timespan'] that match the input year in ['creation'].

```
def time(year):
    my_ocan['creation'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_ocan['creation']).year
    t = my_ocan.loc[my_ocan['creation'] == year, 'timespan'].sum()
    return t
    #returns 0, when running with 2015 and with all the others
```

How can I get the sum of all the values in ['timespan'] that were created in a particular year?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, can we see the output from `do_process_citation_data`?

Comment: @Fred hey! Thank you for having a look at my question, I updated the output for do_process_citation_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is as follows

```
# Get the number of citations in a year
len(my_ocan[my_ocan["creation"].dt.year==2015].index)

# Get the total timespan in a year
my_ocan[my_ocan["creation"].dt.year==2015]["timespan"].sum()
```

The basic logic for filtering a DataFrame in Pandas is as follows

```
# 1. Establish Filter Logic
my_ocan["timespan"] == 365
# Returns
 1  False
 2  False
 3  False
 4  False
 5  True

#Use this result as a filter
my_ocan[my_ocan["timespan"] == 365]

# This will only return the corresponding rows where the filter returned True, thus for your example data set you'll get a single line of data
```

For Pandas columns that have a date time type, you can access lots of date time functions using the dt accessor, have a look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dt-accessor

An example of how to use the dt accessor:

```
my_ocan["creation"].head()
# Returns
1   2016-07-10
2   2018-03-01
3   2018-01-01
4   2017-06-13
5   2017-01-01

# But using the dt accessor we can quickly get the year
my_ocan["creation"].dt.year.head()
# Returns
1   2016
2   2018
3   2018
4   2017
5   2017
```

To bring this all together and create your tuple function:

```
def get_citations_per_year(df, year):
    citation_count = len(my_ocan[my_ocan["creation"].dt.year==2015].index)
    timespan_sum = my_ocan[my_ocan["creation"].dt.year==2015]["timespan"].sum()
    return (citation_count, timespan_sum)
```

Comment: No worries! Don’t forget to make it as the answer